# Was Nanoha critically injured during a Jail Scaglietti Investigation?

Tags: nanoha

During *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS* it's revealed that between *StrikerS* and the end of *A's*, as Nanoha pushed her body too much without proper rest, she got injured during a mission with Vita to the point where she could have never walked/flown again.

During the battle in Saint's Cradle, when Vita comes across spider like Gadget Drones, she remembers seeing them during the mission which led to Nanoha being critically injured, and she lets out her anger on them because they were apparently responsible for almost ruining Nanoha's life.

I am wondering, was the mission Vita and Nanoha did together where Nanoha was critically injured a Jail Scaglietti Investigation? If not, then what was the connection between Jail's Drones and that mission?

Answer (score 1):

Before the events of *StrikerS*, although Jail Scaglietti's existence was a secret known only to the top tiers of the TSAB, his activities were already known, albeit the identity of its perpetrator remained unknown. In fact, said activities are one of the main points Hayate used during his exposition when forming Riot Force 6.

We can only deduce that Nanoha's incident happened in one encounter with Scaglietti's activities. Still, as there was no "Jail Scaglietti Investigation" back then, she must have been investigating a case of improper use of Lost Logia or usage of magical technology in an underdeveloped world (not specified, as far as I know)

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a source from where you got your answer?